# Clear terminal history after less is closed

Tags: command-history, privacy

Basically, I need the following:

- run a command with confidential input
- pipe output to `less`
- clear history with `less` output on screen (or at the moment it is closed)

The idea is to make sure that after I have closed `less` nobody can restore the command input.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo -ne '\033]50;ClearScrollback\a'` should work.
To chain it with less you can execute `less some-file && echo -ne '\033]50;ClearScrollback\a'`
To prevent the command from saving in your bash history add the following to your .bash_profile `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` save it and exit. Then in the prompt type `. .bash_profile` that will re-read the bash_profile. Now when you run the less command start it with a space before less and it won't get saved to your history.

Comment: How should I chain it with less?

Comment: `less some-file && echo -ne '\033]50;ClearScrollback\a'` then when you hit `q` after you are done reading the file it will automatically run that command. Of course you replace some-file with the file you are opening with less

Comment: Tried on Mac and Ubuntu. command I still available in history

Comment: go into your .bash_profile and add `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` then save and exit. after that type into your prompt `. .bash_profile` and hit enter, this will source (reload) the file. Then when you run the less command start it with a space before it, and it won't get saved to your history.

Comment: Please, add to answer above. I'll mark the answer